# I want r to arrange/merge my resamples in vector

Tags: r, random, split

I have a vector from 1 to 10 which I divided into blocks of size 2 each and then resample the blocks but I am not happy with the result arrangement in r. the below r code demonstrates my experience:

```
ts <- 1:10 # generate a number from 1 to 10
bs <- 2 # let block size equals 2
nb <- length(ts) / bs # number of blocks
blk <- split(ts, rep(1:nb, each=bs)) # split  the generated numbers into "blk"
res<-sample(blk, replace=T, 20) # resample the blk 20 times with replacement
res # gives me the below result

#$`5`
#[1]  9 10

#$`5`
#[1]  9 10

#$`5`
#[1]  9 10

#$`3`
#[1] 5 6

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`2`
#[1] 3 4

#$`5`
#[1]  9 10

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`4`
#[1] 7 8

#$`4`
#[1] 7 8

#$`4`
#[1] 7 8

#$`4`
#[1] 7 8

#$`4`
#[1] 7 8

#$`3`
#[1] 5 6

#$`2`
#[1] 3 4

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2

#$`1`
#[1] 1 2
```

**I rather want the result like:**

(9,10,9,10,9,10,5,6,1,2,3,4,9,10,1,2,1,2,1,2,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,7,8,5,6,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2)

such that I can call "res" as a univariate and I should be able to write the result into either one line or one column .csv file like this:

```
write.csv(res, "resamples.csv")
```

Comment: So, you just want to get a vector instead of a list? Is that the question? If so, do `unlist`.

Comment: yes a vector, as I demonstrated

Comment: Have you tried `unlist(res, use.names = F)`?

Comment: It works but will like you create time to put it as an answer for record purpose

Comment: If you just want a vector in the end why not do `sample(ts, 40, replace=TRUE)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah such is not my desire, I want the block structure maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unlist()` to flatten the list structure. You can also remove the auto-generated names if you don't want/need them:

```r
ts <- 1:10 # generate a number from 1 to 10
bs <- 2 # let block size equals 2
nb <- length(ts) / bs # number of blocks
blk <- split(ts, rep(1:nb, each=bs)) # split  the generated numbers into "blk"
res<-unlist(sample(blk, replace=TRUE, 20)) # resample the blk 20 times with replacement
names(res) <- NULL # optional
res
#>  [1]  3  4  9 10  1  2  7  8  3  4  3  4  7  8  5  6  7  8  3  4  1  2  3
#> [24]  4  9 10  5  6  7  8  9 10  9 10  5  6  9 10  1  2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>